# How to decorate a dependency but only within child container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, structuremap

### The problem

Let's say I have a third party code that is capable of registering an `IService` in a *StructureMap* dependency container. The third party owns both the interface and the implementation.

The goal is to provide a mechanism for modifying the behavior of the `IService` on demand. That is, I want to be able to dynamically choose between the base and modified version throughout the lifetime of my application.

To make things harder, I never actually pull `IService` directly from the container, but rather there's a lot of already existing services that consume `IService` as a dependency, and even more services that depend on `IService` indirectly.

Please note that I do not want to completely replace the functionality of original `IService`, but rather slightly modify values that it returns.

### A proposed solution

It seems to be an obvious choice to use a decorator pattern in order to modify the behavior of the original `IService`. Since I'd like to keep the selection logic out of existing consumer services, and in order to avoid refactoring the existing code I cannot expose the decorated version of `IService` as different type, such as `IDecoratedService`.

Due to performance issues (some of the services use cached data) I would like to avoid creating two independent containers (which would also mean caching the data twice). So it seems like using a child container is a perfect solution (a nested container would also be fine).

### An example

Let's say this is the third party code:

```
public interface IService { string Text { get; } }

public class ThirdPartyRegistry : Registry
{
    private class Service : IService { public string Text => "Service"; }

    public ThirdPartyRegistry()
    {
        For<IService>().Use<Service>();
    }
}
```

Note that I do not have access to the class implementing the service.

What I want to achieve is to create a child container that when asked for an `IService` would return a decorated version of the service provided by the third party.

Here's an example registry that is supposed to do that:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    private class ServiceDecorator : IService
    {
        private readonly IService _service;

        public ServiceDecorator(IService service) { _service = service; }

        public string Text => _service.Text + ", but decorated";
    }

    public MyRegistry()
    {
        // What do I do here?
    }
}
```

The requirement is that when we ask the parent container for the `IService`, we get the original implementation, but if we ask the child container, we get the decorated version.

Here's a simple test fixture (using *NUnit*) that pictures the requirements:

```
public class Tests
{
    private IContainer _parentContainer;
    private IContainer _childContainer;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _parentContainer = new Container(x => x.AddRegistry<ThirdPartyRegistry>());
        _childContainer = _parentContainer.CreateChildContainer();
        _childContainer.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Parent_container_should_return_undecorated_service()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(
            "Service",
            _parentContainer.GetInstance<IService>().Text);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Child_container_should_return_decorated_service()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(
            "Service, but decorated",
            _childContainer.GetInstance<IService>().Text);
    }
}
```

### Failed attempts

I tried achieving my goal using these methods (inside the `MyRegistry` constructor), but without success:

- `For<IService>().DecorateAllWith<ServiceDecorator>()` - this passes the second test, but fails the first one. That is, it also overrides the behavior of `IService` in the parent container, which it shouldn't.
- `For<IService>().Use<ServiceDecorator>()` - this fails the second test with a message saying something like "Bi-directional dependency relationship detected!", which is not surprising.
- `Forward<ServiceDecorator, IService>()` - same as above.

The key problem seems to be to tell the child container to use `IService` instance registered by the third party registry to construct the `ServiceDecorator`.

Note that I'd be perfectly happy to modify the code depicted in the test class. In particular how the parent and child containers are set up (the contents of the `SetUp` method).

Comment: [just thinking out of the box here] Would it work instead when you inject the decorator with some contextual dependency that allows to to tell the decorator whether it should apply its logic, or short-circuit directly to its decoratee? That would allow the decorator to be applied always and unconditional, while you can control the flag on that contextual dependency higher up the call stack.

Comment: I think it could work, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. What I'm after is a kind of plugin architecture, where there's no central point that knows of all plugins and when to use them. This smells of defeating the purpose of IoC. I guess I could get around that by doing a "decorator inception", i.e. have a chain of decorators, each dedicated to a single plugin. I think you should go ahead and post it as an answer. I'll see if any other answers are submitted before accepting, but at least you'll earn an upvote.